# Lync and OCS 2007 R2 Side by Side

Tags: ms-office-communicator, lync

Im wondering if i can install LYNC as a test basis side by side by the production OCS 2007 R2.

They would both be in the same domain, but off course on seperate domains.

Reason i ask is because i know LYNC does a schema update, and i wanna make sure this does not  conflic with existing OCS

Comment: your question is confusing.  You say they would be in same domain but then on separate domains.  Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a migration allows both pools to run in the same AD domain at the same time, but I would not recommend installing Lync 2010 in a production AD domain until I had a plan and knew how to deploy it.  Test/learn on a different test AD domain.